# Convert multiple json strings to dataset in c#

Tags: c#, json

Below is my json string and I wanted it to convert to readable format in c# so that i can convert to dataset. Please advise.

ITCFScenario12

```
{
    ""TC"":{
        ""test_case"":""ITCFScenario12"",
        ""data_type"":""testcomplete"",
    }
    ""3"":{
    ""scenariodescription"":""Create Client"",
    },
    ""7"":{
    ""scenariodescription"":""CreateServicePlan"",
    },
},
```

ITCFScenario13

```
{
    ""TC"":{
        ""test_case"":""ITCFScenario12"",
        ""data_type"":""testcomplete"",
    }
    ""3"":{
    ""scenariodescription"":""Create Client"",
    },
    ""7"":{
    ""scenariodescription"":""CreateServicePlan"",
    },
},
```

Comment: The NewtonSoft jSOn framework gives you a lot of good tool for these kinds of operations:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

First make you data models to fit your jSon data and then let this library do the legwork.

Comment: I have tried a lot in Visual Studio using NewtonSoft Json framework but couldn't resolve it to a readable format as the data I get from Json is dynamic. I updated the the format that gets dynamically generated:

Comment: Well there must be some kind of structure to the data or else it'll be pretty unusable for yout program.
Unless you just want to thow it and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON object is not in valid format.
It should look like below,

```
{
    "TC":{
        "test_case":"ITCFScenario12",
        "data_type":"testcomplete"

    },
    "3":{
    "scenariodescription":"Create Client"
    },
    "7":{
    "scenariodescription":"CreateServicePlan"
    }
}
```

Use any online tools to validate the JSON object. TO check it's in correct format or not.
https://jsonformatter.org/
So if you are getting it from front end, it's need to be corrected.

Once its in correct format Newtonsoft JSON framework can use for all other operations.